# How to specify a profile in a Micronaut application?

Tags: java, frameworks, microservices, profile, micronaut

I want to specify different types of configs depending on the environment that I will deploy the app. Like in Spring-boot in the yml file we can set the profile, I want to know if there is a way to do it in Micronaut.

Answer (score 18):

You can set active environment(s) either by *system property* **`micronaut.environments`** (`java -Dmicronaut.environments=foo,bar -jar myapp.jar`) or by *environment variable* **`MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS`**.

See Documentation: https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#environments

Comment: We also support config files like `application-gcp.yml`, which would only be loaded if running on GCP (for example).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example of how to build and run Micronaut using environment variables and CMD in Win 10 with prod profile:

```
gradlew clean build -x test -x integrationTest
set MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=prod
echo %MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS%
java -jar build/libs/app.jar
```

Don't forget to check the environment in the console log after starting. Search for: "Environment(s):   [prod]".

Solution with system property (java -Dmicronaut.environments=foo,bar -jar myapp.jar) does not work for me, but under Ubuntu/Mac it works fine.
I'm using micronautVersion=2.4.4

Comment: I could not get the system property way working either and I am in Micronaut version 3.5.4 but using the Shell variable worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this with gradle and the run task, you can take the following approach.

***build.gradle***

```
run {
    systemProperties([
        'micronaut.environments': 'local'
    ])
}
```

This by default will read from `application.yaml` and `application-local.yaml`